# issues to inspect a long text file in unix

Tags: tail

If I run

```
sudo pico /var/log/lighttpd/website/error.log
```

I get a very long file, and I cannot see last lines. If I run:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/lighttpd/website/error.log | awk '{print $1 "--"  $2}'
```

I don't get anything ? What am I doing wrong ?

Also, how can I move to a specific line using pico editor ?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would better to use some pager program like `less`. It tries not to load the whole file into memory, so it works well with large files. In less you can move to a specific line by typing `:123` where 123 is line number you need.

As for tail - are you getting anything without awk? Or with `sudo tail -n 10 -f <log>`?

Answer (score 2):

The `-f` flag in tail means "Keep the tail process running and if the file changes, chuck them onto `STDOUT`". Basically, it's a neat way of actively watching a log file.

I believe the pipe will wait for the first program to finish writing to `STDOUT` before throwing the output into `awk`. Because of the `-f` flag, tail never quits (until you tell it) so nothing ever gets piped into `awk`. Therefore nothing gets printed.

Try the second command without the `-f`. If you're looking for `-f` functionality but also with mangling the output with awk, I'm not sure what the answer is, short of writing a custom script to do it...

Comment: Nope, pipe won't wait for the first program. There might be some buffer, but I've never faced any problems and noticeable delays with it using `tail -f <something> | grep <...>` or `tail -f <something> | awk <...>`

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

`tail -f` never quits as long as the file still exists (and I think after that too). Nothing gets passed through the pipe until the first process has died.

If you want the functionality of tail -f (i.e. monitoring the file) while still piping it through awk, try `watch "tail /var/log/lighttpd/website/error.log | awk '{print \$1 \"--\"  \$2}'"`